# Idiomatic TypeScript to provide default in case of [undefined,undefined]?

Tags: typescript

I am invoking D3's [extent](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-array/index.d.ts#L76) function from TypeScript. Since I am dealing with numbers, its return type is `[number, number] | [undefined, undefined]`.

What's the idiomatic way to provide a default value in case of `[undefined,undefined]`?

I ended up writing a helper function:

```
import { extent } from 'd3-array';

...

/**
 * Provides a safe [0, 0] default for potentially undefined value pairs.
 */
export const safe = ([x, y]: [number, number] | [undefined, undefined]): [number, number] => {
    if (x === undefined || y === undefined) {
        return [0, 0];
    } else {
        return [x, y] as [number, number];
    }
};

const safeExtent = safe(extent(values));
```

But I am looking for a more elegant/idiomatic way, something along the lines of `Option(extent).getOrElse([0, 0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a native TypeScript/JavaScript function that handles some kind of defined state based on array values. Calling the reduce function isn't necessary on an array that contains exactly two values.

I would do it this way:

```js
export function safe([x, y]: [number|undefined, number|undefined]): [number, number] {
    return (x === undefined || y === undefined) ? [0, 0] : [x, y];
}
```

Tests:

```js
// = [0, 0]
safe([undefined, 1])

// = [0, 0]
safe([1, undefined])

// = [0, 0]
safe([undefined, undefined])

// = [1, 1]
safe([1, 1])

// = [null, null]
safe([null, null])
```

**Side-notes:** I prefer to export function declarations over function type literals (lambda notion) but I think that it is a matter of taste.

However, it does make a difference to use functions vs. const lambdas within a class because the *this* is defined to be the class instance within a const lambda member.

I think *as* does not need to be called on a return type if the function declares the return type.

**Update:** You could also use a type declaration:

```js
export type numberOpt = number | undefined;

export function safe([x, y]: [numberOpt, numberOpt]): [number, number] {
    return (x === undefined || y === undefined) ? [0, 0] : [x, y];
}
```

However, that means one more export.

**Update 2:** Even better because more generic and therefore closer to your question:

```js
export type Option<T> = T | undefined;

export function safe([x, y]: [Option<number>, Option<number>]): [number, number] {
    return (x === undefined || y === undefined) ? [0, 0] : [x, y];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are correct, _as_ was not necessary. Wrt input parameter types, I think that my signature is stricter (because it doesn't allow 'mixed' tuples in the first place), right? Overall our implementations are pretty much identical, except that your ternary operator makes yours a bit shorter.

Comment: Yes, you are right - your type definition is stricter. I couldn't find a better implementation of the function than yours.

Answer (score 0):

will this work?

```
type optionalNumber = number | undefined

export const safe = ([x, y]: [optionalNumber, optionalNumber]): [
    number,
    number
] => {
    return [x, y].map(num => num || 0)
}
```

**Update 1**

After my misunderstanding of question and your explanation in the comment, I could only come up with following:

```
export const safe = ([x, y]: [number, number] | [undefined, undefined]): [
    number,
    number
] => {
    return [x, y].map(num => num || 0) as [number, number]
}
```

[I see .map() takes away the tuple-ness of the tuple](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6574)

Given the homogenous nature of the input, it works and imo looks cleaner, but I dont know if this is the most idiomatic way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am afraid, this doesn't even compile. Your `map` call returns `number[]` (an array) rather than `[number, number]` (a tuple). Moreover, your input param is now less restrictive, a mixed tuple [number, undefined] would now be allowed (which is not necessary).

Comment: @netzwerg sorry I misunderstood your problem. but this is very interesting issue. I would love to know the solution too.